# Reverse proxy cannot load ssl certificates

Tags: docker, ssl, nginx

I am trying to run an nginx proxy in a docker container, coupled to a letsencrypt container that generates and updates the certificates.

Without ssl enabled the configuration runs fine
with ssl enabled i get the following error

> emerg] 1#1: cannot load certificate "/etc/ssl/private/fullchain.pem":
> BIO_new_file() failed (SSL: error:02001002:system library:fopen:No
> such file or directory:fopen('/etc/ssl/private/fullchain.pem','r')
> error:2006D080:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:no such file) reverse_proxy
> | nginx: [emerg] cannot load certificate
> "/etc/ssl/private/fullchain.pem": BIO_new_file() failed (SSL:
> error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or
> directory:fopen('/etc/ssl/private/fullchain.pem','r')
> error:2006D080:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:no such file)

the following is my configuration

**/conf.d/sites-avaidable/heimdall.conf**

```
  upstream heimdall {
  server        192.168.178.215:8888;
}

server {
  listen        443 ssl;
  #listen       80;
  server_name   heimdall.domain.tld;

   include      common.conf;
   include      /etc/nginx/ssl.conf;

  location / {
    proxy_pass  http://192.168.178.215:8888;
    include     common_location.conf;

  }
}
```

And from /etc/nginx

**nginx.conf**

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  1;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/sites-enabled/*.conf;
}
```

**common.conf**

```
add_header Strict-Transport-Security    "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains" always;
add_header X-Frame-Options              SAMEORIGIN;
add_header X-Content-Type-Options       nosniff;
add_header X-XSS-Protection             "1; mode=block";
```

**common_location.conf**

```
proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP           $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For     $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Proto   $scheme;
proxy_set_header    Host                $host;
proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Host    $host;
proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Port    $server_port;
```

ssl.conf

```
ssl_protocols               TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
ssl_ecdh_curve              secp384r1;
ssl_ciphers                 "ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA512:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA512:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384 OLD_TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256 OLD_TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_CH$
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers   on;
ssl_dhparam                 /etc/nginx/dhparams.pem;
ssl_certificate             /etc/ssl/private/fullchain.pem;
ssl_certificate_key         /etc/ssl/private/privkey.pem;
ssl_session_timeout         10m;
ssl_session_cache           shared:SSL:10m;
ssl_session_tickets         off;
ssl_stapling                on;
ssl_stapling_verify         on;
```

/etc/ssl/private is filled with symlinks to the certificates, that are generated by another docker container.
mounting  the directory directly leads to the exact same behaviour.

Here is the folder that is mounted at /etc/ssl/private

```
total 28
drwxr-xr-x 2 pi pi 4096 juin  22 20:19 .
drwxr-xr-x 4 pi pi 4096 juin  22 22:39 ..
lrwxrwxrwx 1 pi pi   69 juin  22 20:19 cert.pem -> /home/pi/letsencrypt/config/etc/letsencrypt/live/site.tld/cert.pem
lrwxrwxrwx 1 pi pi   70 juin  22 20:19 chain.pem -> /home/pi/letsencrypt/config/etc/letsencrypt/live/site.tld/chain.pem
lrwxrwxrwx 1 pi pi   74 juin  22 20:19 fullchain.pem -> /home/pi/letsencrypt/config/etc/letsencrypt/live/site.tld/fullchain.pem
lrwxrwxrwx 1 pi pi   72 juin  22 20:19 privkey.pem -> /home/pi/letsencrypt/config/etc/letsencrypt/live/site.tld/privkey.pem
lrwxrwxrwx 1 pi pi   67 juin  22 20:19 README -> /home/pi/letsencrypt/config/etc/letsencrypt/live/site.tld/README
```

and here is the symlink target folder

```
total 12
drwxr-xr-x 2 pi pi 4096 juin  22 16:03 .
drwx------ 4 pi pi 4096 juin  22 16:23 ..
lrwxrwxrwx 1 pi pi   35 juin  22 16:03 cert.pem -> ../../archive/site.tld/cert1.pem
lrwxrwxrwx 1 pi pi   36 juin  22 16:03 chain.pem -> ../../archive/site.tld/chain1.pem
lrwxrwxrwx 1 pi pi   40 juin  22 16:03 fullchain.pem -> ../../archive/site.tld/fullchain1.pem
lrwxrwxrwx 1 pi pi   38 juin  22 16:03 privkey.pem -> ../../archive/site.tld/privkey1.pem
-rw-r--r-- 1 pi pi  692 juin  22 16:03 README
```

and here is a ls -la from a terminal inside the container

```
root@reverse_proxy:/etc/ssl/private# ls -la
total 12
drwxr-xr-x 2 1000 1000 4096 Jun 22 14:03 .
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4096 Jun  9 05:06 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 1000 1000  692 Jun 22 14:03 README
lrwxrwxrwx 1 1000 1000   35 Jun 22 14:03 cert.pem -> ../../archive/site.tld/cert1.pem
lrwxrwxrwx 1 1000 1000   36 Jun 22 14:03 chain.pem -> ../../archive/site.tld/chain1.pem
lrwxrwxrwx 1 1000 1000   40 Jun 22 14:03 fullchain.pem -> ../../archive/site.tld/fullchain1.pem
lrwxrwxrwx 1 1000 1000   38 Jun 22 14:03 privkey.pem -> ../../archive/site.tld/privkey1.pem
```

I do hope someone can point me in the right direction
i searched and searched, regenerated my dhparams.pem but nothing i find seems to fix my issue.

Comment: It clearly says for `/etc/ssl/private/fullchain.pem` that *"No such file or directory"*. So make sure that exactly this file is actually there and accessible. No idea why you try to fiddle with dhparams.pem since it is not complaining about this.

Comment: that was the first thing i checked. the symlink seems to  be placed correctly. Ill update the post to show that

Comment: So you've checked that the file is readable __from within the container__ where nginx is running and __as the user nginx__ inside this container?

Comment: It is unclear from your question where these symlinks finally end up and what access permissions the target files have. Again, please check that the file is actually readable from within the container as the user nginx.

Comment: from inside the container all files are with those permissions: lrwxrwxrwx should be readable by anyone

Comment: Not only the symlink must be readable but after all the symlinks are resolved there is hopefully a file at the end and its permissions matters to. Only all you show are symlinks. Please do an actual `cat` on the file to see if it can be read and do the `cat` as user nginx.

Comment: so if i do a cat as the user nginx on the symlink, the file is not readable. i do have a problem figuring out why. the container that grabs the letsencrypt certificates seems to store them in an archive folder but under a different name. I do ear that changing permissions on the files in the archive folder will only last me untill the stuff gets renewed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ran into the same issue when trying to build a Nexus deployment with Nginx.  The container can't traverse the symlinks in the ssl.conf since your pointers to your letencrypt keys point from live --> archive.

To resolve this you can't just change the pointer to archive since files like

`chain.pem -> ../../archive/site.tld/chain1.pem`

The only way I could get this to work was to point not to the symlink but the actual file on disk. Note the `1` in the filename which matches whats on disk.

My /etc/ssl/private

```
ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/private/fullchain1.pem;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/privkey1.pem;
ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/ssl/private/chain1.pem;
ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/dhparams.pem;
```

So in my `docker-compose.yml` You can see me mount the volume

```
    volumes:
      - /etc/letsencrypt/archive/example.site.com:/etc/ssl/private
```

I am sure there is a more elegant way but this is the only way I could get this to work.

Answer (score 2):

I had exactly the same issue, and I just added the linked folder in the volumes section of the docker-compose.yml file, something like this ...

```
  nginx:
    ...
    volumes:
      - /home/pi/letsencrypt/config/etc/letsencrypt/live/site.tld/:/etc/ssl/private/site.tld/
      - /home/pi/letsencrypt/config/etc/letsencrypt/archive/site.tld/:/home/pi/letsencrypt/config/etc/letsencrypt/archive/site.tld/
```

Maybe this could be not the best approach, another one could be just share the archive folder instead, or have another folder arrangement; the think is, that inside the container docker cannot find the linked file.

I hope this can be useful for you.